# How to get datatype of a column in Scala dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, types

How can I get the datatype of column from a dataframe in Scala. I found some answers here and there but non of them are helpful and exact.

For example there is column X with data type (StringStype) and after doing:

```
     scala> df.select("X").dtypes
     res: Array[(String, String)] = Array((X,StringType))
```

I am not sure why it returns array while it is only a string.

What I am looking for to exactly return "StringType" without any extra information and cleaned to be able to play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I was looking for:

```
 scala> df.select("X").dtypes(0)._2
 res: String = StringType
```

At least closer to what I need and cleaner to play with.